# System.IO.FileNotFoundException when using WebGrease via Commandline

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, command-prompt, webgrease

I'm trying to use **WebGrease 1.6** via command line (also tried Developer Command Prompt for VS2013). When I run "`wg options`", I'm getting following error (screenshot attached)

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.6.5135.21930, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
at WebGrease.Program.Main(String[] args)

[image: error screenshot]

I tried on 3 different development machines. Same issue is present on all.

I'm using:

- WebGrease.1.6.0
- Visual Studio 2013 Update 3
- Windows 8.1 (64 bit)

What am I missing? 
Any help solving this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem. However, if you copy the **WebGrease.dll** file from the *lib* folder to the *tools* folder it will work.

Answer (score 1):

for other ppl strugglin in the same problem as us..

you need these dll in the same folder as wg.exe

Antlr3.Runtime.dll

Newtonsoft.Json.dll